# Netlify Deploy Fails: react-scripts: not found

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, yarnpkg, serverless, netlify

The app was built with create-react-app.
Everything works fine locally. However, I kept getting this error from Netlify
I've tried to install react-scripts but it didn't work. Same error causing Netlify deployment failure.

Netlify Log Details -

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.17
$ cd client && npm run build
my-app@0.1.0 build
react-scripts build
sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error message
Command failed with exit code 127: yarn build

Error location
In Build command from Netlify app:
yarn build
```

package.json file in my client folder

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8888",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.1.2",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-core": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-expiration": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-precaching": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-routing": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-strategies": "^5.1.3",
    "workbox-streams": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my dependencies?